# Do I have to include my second passport in my UK Visa application?

Tags: visas

The US allows it's citizens to have a second passport if your primary passport is held up in a visa application. I have accumulated travel on my second passport but I am wondering if I have to include that travel in my travel history (and the passport) when submitting an application for my primary passport?

Comment: The question is relevant for people with other nationalities than US. But note that if you're a US citizen and need a visa for the UK, then it is likely not an ordinary visitor visa, and then your purpose is probably something that is better dealt with at [Expats.SE].

Comment: Your travel history should include all of your foreign travel regardless of what document you used.

Comment: @henning People who have had previous difficulties at UK immigration might elect to apply for a visitors visa to avoid a repeat of such trouble. There are a number of questions on this site on exactly that topic.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The question isn't specific to long-term visas, so there's no reason whatsoever to migrate to Expatriates. Also, if you feel that a question is off-topic, then please don't answer it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I said explicitly that I don't think the question is offtopic because it is a relevant issue for other nationalities too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You weren't explicit at all. If you'd been explicit, I wouldn't have thought you meant the opposite of what you were actually trying to say, and maybe two people wouldn't have voted to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

If the application form asks for your travel history, it means *your* international travel history, not where the passport you happen to apply with has been. Leaving things out counts as *lying on a visa application* -- which spells doom not only for that application but for your interactions with UK visa and immigration authorities for a long, long time afterwards.

You can't be expected to submit both passports with the visa application, though; that would defeat the purpose of having an additional passport. But it's probably a good idea to explain in your application *that* you have a second passport, to avoid confusion arising from the fact that the travel history you're describing should have resulted in more stamps than they can see in the passport you submit.

Comment: They already ask about all passports issued in the last 20 years. The mandatory document list only includes the current passport. Previous passports are not mandatory to submit.

Comment: @greatone in this case there are two current passports.

Comment: @phoog only one passport is mandatory. You just have to mention any others--valid or not. Same nationality or different.

Comment: @greatone that may be, but "the current passport" implies a single current passport, so the proper course of action is left to speculation.  Is there anything that explicitly discusses what to do in this case, or at lease says "a current passport" rather than "the current passport"?

Comment: @phoog my bad. it doesn't say "current passport." Just passport and other passport(a) that you may have.